# add app to facebook fan page error

Tags: facebook

I am trying to add an app to my facebook fan page account for oAuth login.
I DONT WANT A TAB so the method i thought might work was `method: 'apprequests'`
but i keep getting an error: 
`An error occurred with Prayerfish Login. Please try again later.`

any suggestions on how to get the app over to my fan page?

**note**** this html page is from [facebooks tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <title>My Add to Page Dialog Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='fb-root'></div>
        <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
        <p><a onclick='addToPage(); return false;'>Add to Page</a></p>
        <p id='msg'></p>

        <script> 
            FB.init({appId: "****************", status: true, cookie: true});

            function addToPage() {

                // calling the API ...
                var obj = {
                    //method: 'pagetab',
                    method: 'apprequests',
                    redirect_uri: 'https://www.myDomain.com',
                };

                FB.ui(obj);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to have an app on a Facebook Page is to add it as a "tab". Since the switch to Timeline, tab has become a bit of a misnomer as it is more correct that it is just a bookmark at the top of your Page (for example on [Spotify's Page](https://www.facebook.com/Spotify?ref=ts) the 'Get Spotify', 'Fan Playlist' and 'Summer Sounds' thumbnails at the top of the page are technically 'Page Tabs').

If you still want to add the app to your Page as a 'tab', the code you included above is actually more complex than you need. That code is what you would include on your website, for example, if you wanted to allow admins of *other* Facebook Pages to install your app. Because you own both the Page and the app, you just need to modify this link to include your app ID and URL and click on it:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=YOUR_APP_URL

When you do, you'll see a dialog asking you to pick which Page you want to add the app to, choose that and you're done.

If you were already aware of what a Page Tab is and don't want that, my question would be - how do you want the app to appear?

Comment: this app is for oAuth, there wouldnt be any content, so it should not be visible for visitors.  i would need a few `user & friend permissions`.  and again this is for a fan page

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "this app is for oAuth" - do you mean for authenticating users?

Comment: That isn't possible - you can't include HTML into the Page itself, so the only way is to get users to go to a Page tab, click some kind of 'authenticate' button and get the permissions from them.

Comment: i think theres been a misunderstanding,  i added a note to my question.  I am trying to add an app, the html is not client facing.

Comment: Then your terminology is incorrect, you can't 'add an app to a page' except via the page tab mechanism outlined at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/